# Do something only once Python

Tags: python

I have this sequence of numbers

12345  do something
12345
12345
12346 do something
12346
12346
12346
12347 do something
12347
12347
12347

The numbers are repeated unknown number of times
I just need to do something on the first change

Comment: Have you tried saving the current element to a temporary variable, and then checking if the new one is the same as the saved one?

Answer (score 0):

you might have made an infinite loop please send your code so that we can help you

so stop you program press ctrl +c.

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to set a boolean saying whether you've already done the thing. Something like:

```
have_done_something=False

if number_changed and not have_done_something:
    have_done_something=True
    #do something
```